# Notification to devices in an area without the use of an installed app

Tags: firebase, notifications, cloud, push, messaging

I've been working on an idea that I'd like to implement ( I've written a paper on it) . The method that I've mentioned includes sending notifications to android users present in an area without specifically installing my app. 
First, is it possible?
Second, I've looked into Firebase cloud messaging- I'm aware that it should be tethered to an app but is it necessary that the user has to download the app?
Third, are there any other methods by which this type of push notifications can be sent? ( Based on location)
Finally, I'm sorry if you feel I haven't​ put any effort I'm new to this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such a service is known as [Cell Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast) when talking about SMS/Text messaging.

There is nothing built in for it in Firebase Cloud Messaging. Even if there was, it would require an app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: Ok so FCM requires an app. But is there a way for the user to just subscribe to the service? I don't want the user to waste storage space by installing another app.

Comment: When you use the Firebase Cloud Messaging SDK in your app, it includes the code needed to receive messages. Without the app, or without the FCM SDK, there is no way to receive FCM messages. I'm pretty sure that applies for all messaging services that don't rely on SMS: they'll need some code to run on the phone to be receiving the messages.